# How do I get over a SQL Server error MSG 8134 Divide by zero error encountered Error in my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I am trying to calculate percentage changes between 2 columns and get a Divide by zero error encountered error. I want to display all Nulls as 0 but if I use ISNULL I get this error. How do I get over this?

```
SELECT
   Table2014.OrderDate AS [December2014OrderDate],
   ISNULL(Table2014.Total, 0) AS [December2014DailySales],
   ISNULL(Table2013.Total, 0) AS [December2013DailySales],
   ISNULL(Table2014.Total, 0) - ISNULL(Table2013.Total, 0) AS [DailySalesDifference],
   100.0 * (ISNULL(Table2014.Total, 0) - ISNULL(Table2013.Total, 0)) / ISNULL(Table2013.Total, 0) AS [SalesDifferencePercentage],
   ISNULL(Table2013.OrderCount, 0) AS [December2013DailyOrderCount],
   ISNULL(Table2014.OrderCount, 0) AS [December2014DailyOrderCount],  
   ISNULL(Table2014.OrderCount, 0) - ISNULL(Table2013.OrderCount, 0) AS [DailyOrderCountDifference]
FROM 
   (SELECT
       SUM(order_header_total.oht_net) AS Total,
       DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, order_header.oh_datetime)) AS OrderDate,
       COUNT(order_header.oh_id) AS OrderCount
    FROM 
       dbo.order_header_total
    INNER JOIN 
       dbo.order_header ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
    WHERE 
       order_header.oh_datetime BETWEEN '12/01/2014 00:00:00' AND '12/31/2014 23:59:59'
       AND order_header.oh_os_id IN (1, 6, 4)
       AND order_header.oh_cd_id = 76
    GROUP BY 
       DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, order_header.oh_datetime))) Table2014
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT
        SUM(order_header_total.oht_net) AS Total,
        DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, order_header.oh_datetime))) AS OrderDate,
        COUNT(order_header.oh_id) AS OrderCount
     FROM 
        dbo.order_header_total
     INNER JOIN 
        dbo.order_header ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
     WHERE 
        order_header.oh_datetime BETWEEN '12/01/2013 00:00:00' AND '12/31/2013 23:59:59'
        AND order_header.oh_os_id IN (1, 6, 4)
        AND order_header.oh_cd_id = 76
     GROUP BY 
        DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, order_header.oh_datetime)))) Table2013 ON Table2013.OrderDate = Table2014.OrderDate
ORDER BY 
   Table2014.OrderD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Isnull` in `Denominator` use `NULLIF` to handle divide by zero error.

```
select ...
100.0*Isnull((ISNULL(Table2014.Total,0) - ISNULL(Table2013.Total, 0)) / 
                  NULLIF(Table2013.Total, 0) AS [SalesDifferencePercentage],0),
 .....
```

`NullIF` helps to replace the `0` with `Null` in `denominator` which will avoid the mentioned error

Comment: I have tried this which is fine but as i mentioned i still want all NULL's to display in my table as a 0

Comment: @TowelsRus - Updated check now